# using xpath in php does not work with file

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

Applying `xpath()` on SimpleXMLElement object, loaded with XML from a string works. If I load it from a file - it doesn't... I simply get an empty array.

The depth level of the element that I am searching for is 5 (if we say that the root node is 1st level). When on xml from string - it works even with xpath expression that starts from the last level... When on xml from file - no xpath works at all.

The ways I tried loading the xml content into the SimpleXMLElement object were (and applying the `xpath()`):

1.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('filepath/file.xml');
$result = $xml->xpath('//Export/Product/Settings/Info[@Art="Short"]/@Something');
```

2.

```
$xmlStr = file_get_contents('filepath/file.xml'); 
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlStr);
$result = $xml->xpath('//Export/Product/Settings/Info[@Art="Short"]/@Something');
```

Not successful, both of them... When from string just `$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlStr);` worked fine. I looked through [THIS ARTICLE](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) and probably tried almost any suggestion from the comments that seemed reasonable for my case.

Another strange thing I noticed is that when I write in the log the `$xml`, when it's from string I get the output (of arrays and object, etc.) from the depth level of `Product` (which is 2nd). But when I do it with `$xml` that has been loaded from file - I get the output from the root node.

Simple representation of the XML code:

```
<Export>
  <Product>
    ...a lot of other elements...
    <Settings>
      <Info Art="Short" Something="blahblahblah"/>
      <Info Art"asda" Somethig="dsad"/>
      <Info .... />
      ...
    </Settings>
  </Product>
</Export>
```

So my question is - how I get it working when I load the XML from a file, as it works when I load it from a string?

P.S. I don't know if that is relevant with the current problem, but - when I load from string (heredoc), and the string has as first row `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` - I get error of calling `xpath()` on a `non-object`. But as soon as I remove this first row, and the string starts with the root node - everything is flawless.

**UPDATE:** the first `<Export...>` node:

```
<Export xmlns="http://something" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://something C:/some_path/some_file.xsd" GA_Vertriebsweg="2" KomplettExport="true">
```

**UPDATE 2:** The whole thing with loading from file does not work just because of the 1st attribute in `<Export...` as in here: `<Export xmlns="http://www.evelopment.de/schema/katalogexport/komplett"...>`, so the whole problem is in the namespace.

Comment: Are you using any namespaces in your xml? <Export xmlns="">

Comment: @t-coder - I have updated my post with the first line (the `<Export...` node). You can look at it.

Comment: With simplexml_load_file you can specify a namespace. Perhaps that solves it already. If not please upload that XML with the namespace somewhere and link it so one can look into that. And just FYI 1. and 2.) are pretty similar, you can just use 1.) in your case there is no difference between the two.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code and it works just fine.

```
Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [Something] => blahblahblah ) ) )
```

Only 2 changes.

1. You nedd the first line in your xml to be `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`
2. You are missing an equal sign 
   `<Info Art"asda" Somethig="dsad"/>` 
   should be 
   `<Info Art="asda" Somethig="dsad"/>`

For you XML to work, you have to to register a namespace prefix:

```
$xml->registerXPathNamespace("w", "http://something");
```

You can read more here: [link](http://web.archive.org/web/20090414184326/http://people.ischool.berkeley.edu/~felix/xml/php-and-xmlns.html)

Comment: In the file itslef - I have the 1st line like that (as you said). About the equal sign - I missed it now, as I was writing the post. Otherwise I don't have them missing... :D

Comment: I updated my post with noting what exactly causes the problem.
(P.S. I didn't see the edit on your answer about the namespaces...)